# spring security user doesn't load on authenticationmanagerbuilder

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

Hello fellow junior developers, in a project with spring framework + hibernate + spring security + jsf I have quite a problem, when checking a logged user into the builder of spring security, I can easily retrieve the user from the .xhtml and check the database but when I am passing the user to spring security it doesn't activate.

The part on my customUserDetail where I transfer the user to the SecurityConfig class is the following

```
public org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("das"+ usuario_login.getDas());
    System.out.println("pass"+ usuario_login.getPassword());



        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities =   buildUserAuthority(usuario_login.getRoles());
        return buildUserForAuthentication(usuario_login, authorities);

    //SecurityConfig sec = new SecurityConfig().configureGlobal(auth);  
}


private User buildUserForAuthentication ( Usuarios user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    return new User(user.getDas(),user.getPassword(),true,true,true,true,authorities);
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Roles roles) {
    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));

    List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);
    return Result;

}
```

the Rol of the user is hardcoded as Role_admin for now. The thing is that even when debugging, everything works fine while doing these 3 previous methods, but then instead loading the `configure (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method of SecurityConfig.class , it just does nothing.

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

`@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }`

When I run the application the first thing it does is load the SecurityConfig.class and its method, but then when the view of login appear and all the verification with the database is done, that builder in SecurityConfig is never used again.

Comment: I actually didn't get what you mean. You trying to figure it out why your SecurityConfig is not called again on each page or other moment you need to verify security? Spring Security loads all user's permissions by the time you log in your application and retains for the session, it doesn't call on all requests.

Comment: i'm trying to know why  configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) in securityConfig class doesn't activate when I pass him parameters, so I can propely use spring security

Comment: Check this link from Baeldung: https://www.baeldung.com/java-config-spring-security. Change method configure to configureGlobal and see if it works

Comment: spring Config is loaded only once when logs in the app that I understands so far. But I assume when i press de submit button on my view and do all the database verificaiton of the user and then userdetailsservice is passed to configure, it had to loaded again right?

Comment: Okay thank you , I'll check it.